# How to get TableName of a DataSet?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tdbgrid, tdataset

How do I get the `TableName` of a `DataSet`?

I tried this:

```
var
  Tblname: string;
begin
  Tblname := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.TableName;
  //it is not working
  //DataSet.TableName is protected
end;
```

Comment: Use RTTI. I'll add an example in a few minutes or so. I had a similar problem using NexusDB instead of TTable. It had all similar properties (jkndexname, tablename etc) but was not derived from TTable

Comment: TDataset descendants do not necessarily have a meaningful TableName, so what you ask is impossible in the general case.  What specific type of TDataSet descendant are you using?  And are you asking about the table name in the back-end RDMS?

Comment: Do you always use the same component, for example TADOTable ? In that case its as simple as `(DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet as TADOTable).TableName`

Answer (score 2):

Using RTTI it is possible to get the value for any property. The example below returns the value of the `TableName` property, provided there is one. I have verified that the code works in a small project.

The main benefit would be that it works on any `TDataset` derived class that has a `TableName` property. (eg `TTable`, but also `TSQLTable` or 
`TFDTable`)

```
....
uses DB,rtti;

function GetTableNameFromDataset(aDataset:TDataset):string;
VAR lTableNameProp:TRttiProperty;
    lContext:TRttiContext;
begin
  Result:='';
  if Assigned(aDataset) then 
  begin
    lContext.Create;
    try
      lTableNameProp:=lContext.GetType(aDataset.ClassInfo).GetProperty('TableName');
      if Assigned(lTableNameProp) then
        Result:=lTableNameProp.GetValue(aDataset).AsString;
    finally
      lContext.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
....
```

Or an alternate solution using the old-style typinfo module (tested on RS 10.3, but I expect it to work on D7 as well)

```
... 
uses DB,typinfo;

function GetTableNameFromDataset(aDataset:TDataset):string;
VAR lPropInfo:PpropInfo;
begin
  Result:='';
  if Assigned(aDataset) then
  begin
    lPropInfo:=GetPropInfo(aDataset.ClassInfo,'TableName');
    if Assigned(lPropInfo) then
      Result:=GetPropValue(aDataset,lPropInfo);
  end;
end;   
...
```

Comment: The use of `with Txxx.Create` is an abomination that Delphi ought not permit, imo.

Comment: Sure, bit it's still a working example. It's not about the with statement, but about how you can get a tablename from a dataset. Changing the TrttiContext into a local variable is easy, I updated the code (untested)

Comment: File Not found 'Rtti.dcu'

Comment: Used version Delphi 7

Comment: Okay, If I find the time I'll add the solution for older delphi releases (using the typinfo unit rathrer than the rtti unit) (I'm at work, anbd the example is at home)

Comment: Used version Delphi 7

Comment: Yes, I took some minutes at work to find solution using typinfo, and verified it works.

Comment: Result:=GetPropValue(aDataset,lPropInfo); 
Error
Incompatible types:'string' and 'PPropInfo'

Comment: Change `GetPropValue()` to `GetStrProp()` instead: `Result := GetStrProp(aDataset, lPropInfo);`

Comment: Thanks me changer TADOTable To TADOQUERY
Result:=Nil
How To use this fonction a 
TTable, TQuery, TadoTable, TadoQuery, Tcommand, TFDTable, TFDQuery..etc

Comment: @Remy, thx/ Obviously some differences between D7 and RS10.3, which supports overloading and D7 does not.

Comment: @Djemoui non-table components simply don't have a `TableName` property.

Comment: In your second solution, `Result:=GetPropValue(aDataset,lPropInfo);` has to be `Result := GetPropValue(aDataset, lPropInfo.Name);` and then this will work in Delphi 7

Comment: @GuidoG Thx, (I don't have D7 up and running here)

Comment: no problem, I still have one here and it only took a minute to test it...